# BadRequestException when creating AWS APIGateway via terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create rest API using terraform however I am getting below error which I am not able to resolve.

```
Error: Error creating API Gateway Integration Response: BadRequestException: Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [No method response exists for method.]
│ 
│   with aws_api_gateway_integration_response.create_report_integration_options_response,
│   on test_api_post.tf line 119, in resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "create_report_integration_options_response":
│  119: resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "create_report_integration_options_response" {
```

Below is the terraform configuration

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}


terraform {
  required_version = "> 0.14.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = "~> 3.0"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "first_api" {
  name = "test-api"
  tags = {
    By = "Terraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "create_report" {
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "create_report"
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "create_report_method" {

  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
  http_method   = "POST"
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.create_report.id
  authorization = "NONE"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "create_report_integration" {
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.create_report_method.http_method
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.create_report.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
  type        = "MOCK"
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode({
      statusCode = 200
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "create_report_integration_response" {
  http_method = "POST"
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.create_report.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
  status_code = 200
  response_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode({

      "message_str" : "report requested, check your phone shortly"

    })
  }

  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "'POST'"
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "'*'",
  }
  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_integration.create_report_integration]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "create_report_method_response" {
  http_method = "POST"
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.create_report.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
  status_code = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : false,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : false,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : false
  }
  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_method.create_report_method, aws_api_gateway_integration.create_report_integration]
}


// options method
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "create_report_options_method" {
  http_method   = "OPTIONS"
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.create_report.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "create_report_options_integration" {
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.create_report_options_method.http_method
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.create_report.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
  type        = "MOCK"
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode({
      statusCode = 200
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "create_report_method_options_response" {
  http_method = "OPTIONS"
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.create_report.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
  status_code = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
  }
  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_method.create_report_options_method, aws_api_gateway_integration.create_report_options_integration]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "create_report_integration_options_response" {
  http_method = "OPTIONS"
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.create_report.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.first_api.id
  status_code = 200
  response_templates = {

  }
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "'POST,OPTIONS'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "'*'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "'true'"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_method.create_report_options_method, aws_api_gateway_integration.create_report_options_integration]
}
```

Could someone please help me out in identifying what I am doing wrong as its been 2 days and I am still not able to figure out what exactly the issue is . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error happens because terraform hasn't finished creating the aws_api_gateway_method_response resources before it starts attempting to create the related aws_api_gateway_integration_responses.

To fix this issue:

- add the `aws_api_gateway_method_response.create_report_method_response` into the aws_api_gateway_integration_response.create_report_integration_response's `depends on` list
- add the `aws_api_gateway_method_response.create_report_method_options_response` into the aws_api_gateway_integration_response.create_report_integration_options_response's `depends on` list.